# Xamarin Build agent not running

Tags: ios, xamarin

When I am trying to build my Xamarin iOS project, I am facing this issue:

> The Xamarin Build Agent is not running on the Mac. An active Build Agent is required to perform the build.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use Visual Studio to compile iOS project, you will need to have a Mac setup with Xamarin for your Visual Studio to connect with (Physical mac or cloud services like mac in cloud). Refer to the xamarin guide [HERE](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/windows/connecting-to-mac/).

Comment: yes we have that it was working fine , but now i am facing this issues

Comment: Is your windows machine able to ssh into the mac machine?

Comment: i solved it by uninstalling xamarin and re-installing it .

Answer (score 0):

You say you uninstalled & reinstalled Xamarin...  do you mean on the Mac?